# Colocate Exchange Server

Tags: exchange

Does anyone have any experience colocating an Exchange Server?  I'm interested in how Active Directory was dealt with and any other pertinent information.  Just to be clear, this is not in regards to "hosting" exchange, but physically colocating an exchange server.  Any and all information will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although I've never done this, I would imagine that connectivity issues to AD located at a different premise would be handled by a persistent VPN. Once that is established, it's like any other server on your network.

Comment: +1. This would be the best choice, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this done.  You'll want the persistent VPN setup like mentioned already, but you'll also most likely want to have the Exchange Server running as a DC (not clean) or have another DC right next to it.  Exchange does a lot of AD lookups so you'll have some performance issues if you do all your lookups across the wire.

Note: The DC needs to be a GC also.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange requires a domain controller to connect to read info from AD so it is best to place a deploy a domain controller in the same location as exchange. This means you will either need a VPN or a dedicated connection back to your other domain controllers. Note you can't deploy a read only domain controller because exchange wont used them and doesn't consider them part of the AD topology. Also the domain controller must be a global catalogue.